# How can I change raw data, from a List type format to the Table?

Tags: excel, text, converters, raw-data

I need to process many rows of grouped data which in the list form like this:

```
Title: Mr.
Name: David
Company: Microsoft

Title: Dr.
Name: John
Company: Facebook

Title: Ms.
Name: Olivia
Company: Google
```

I want to convert this type of data into a simple Table form like this:

```
Title     Name      Company
Mr.       David     Microsoft
Dr.       John      Facebook
Ms.       Olivia    Google
```

I have many tryied with Excel formula and played with these type data to reformat them, but I could not success.

**any idiea in Batch, Powershell, Excel method expected.**

Thanks

Comment: please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What is your Excel version? You may use `TextSplit()` function.

Answer (score 0):

For long dataset it would be best to use ***Power Query***. Alternatively can try below formulas.

```
=VSTACK({"Title","Name","Company"},TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,"Title: ",""),"Name: ",""),"Company: ","")),CHAR(10),"|"))
```

Note: `TEXTJOIN()` has character limit ***32,767*** which is cell character limit of Excel.

[image]